# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 while trying to use swig to wrap c++ library to Python

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am trying to wrap a c++ class in Python using swig. I compiled the class and generated `.o` file and also the wrap file using swig but now when I try to create a library from the files I get the following error.

```
$g++ -lpython -dynamiclib vertex.o vertex_wrap.o -o _vertex.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Cell::removeVertex(Vertex*)", referenced from:
      Vertex::kill(Vertex*) in vertex.o
      Vertex::~Vertex() in vertex.o
      Vertex::~Vertex() in vertex.o
  "Cell::addVertex(Vertex*)", referenced from:
      Vertex::make(Cell*) in vertex.o
      Vertex::Vertex(Cell*) in vertex.o
      Vertex::Vertex(Cell*) in vertex.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vertex` makes calls to a `Cell` (probably, a `Vertex` is typically contained in a `Cell`), namely to `Cell::removeVertex(Vertex*)` and `Cell::addVertex(Vertex*)`. These functions must be defined in some other source file (perhaps `cell.cpp`, just guessing).

So you need to compile the source file `cell.cpp` and link `cell.o` as well (and perhaps other source files if there are more dependencies)

This has nothing to do with SWIG or wrapping for python by the way.

Comment: hey thanks for the info. there are several source files. i was traying to wrap independently by compiling each class file separately. But should I compile all source file together? and create one wrapping for all?

Comment: Normally for a C++ library, you would compile each source file separately and then link them all, e.g. to form a shared library. If you want to wrap this library using swig, you still do this, but you additionally want to generate one swig interface file for the entire library. Swigging gives one wrapper file, which you need to compile in addition to the other source files, and link everything to form one shared library. You can then load this from python and use it.